# Video element in browser silence music apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html5-video

I'm using a video element to play mp4 videos on my website, and I encountered a weird behavior in mobile.

I'm muting and autoplaying my video (according to Chrome/Safari guideline), but when I'm running Spotify/Sound Cloud/other music apps in the background, once my video is playing the music app is being silenced and the OS indicates that the browser is the app that plays sound.

This behavior happen in both iOS 10 and 11 (Safari) and Android (Chrome), and in the beginning it happen on every case related to video - playing when page load, resuming when tab change, resuming when switching to other app and switching back to browser, scrolling to video, etc.

I tried wrapping the video element inside an iframe, but it helped only in several cases - it resolved page load and scrolling issue (every case related to video without leaving the page).

To clarify - **my video element is always muted + volume is set to 0!**

Did anyone have faced issues like this and knows what can cause the OS to identify the browser as the sound playing app?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Asynchronously playing and pausing the video (the video.play/video.pause calls are wrapped by setTimeout for 0 seconds) cause the issue. When immediately calling play/pause, the music app is keep on playing when switching tabs and switching apps.